# How can I fix the same authentication error that reoccurs on multiple accounts?

Tags: git, authentication, github, permissions, account

For some reason I'm having trouble with Git for a long while now. Therefore I decided to ask for a fix on StackOverflow.

I have 3 Git accounts. The last account was made today. Whenever I try to push changes to Git repo I get the following error:

[image: git error]

I get this error on all my accounts. The weird thing the repo that I'm trying to push to is open, not archived, and we are not using SSH Keys. All the git-masters in previous project groups had no idea how to handle this error.

I have to mention that it is possible for me to clone repos and open repos using GitHub Desktop.

Comment: Needless to say that I've tried the 5 things that are summed up in the picture

Comment: It's a general rule that on StackOverflow, you post the content of what you're dealing with rather than linking to it. Links can disappear over time, making them less useful for people who come through having the same problem as you.

Comment: Further, judging from the screenshot, it doesn't look like you're using git itself (which a command line tool), but some git-related gui tool, and you should mention the specific tool. However, if you're getting that while trying to connect to a command line to use git, you have network problems, not git problems.

Comment: To clarify, you are getting this error with Github Desktop? How about using git from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to let the owner of the repo add my account to the contributers list

Comment: So it seems one of the error messages was correct: "_You do not have permission to access this repository._"